# ssh-add error with ECDSA and ED25519 identities

Tags: linux, ssh, ecdsa

Linux environment: Debian 9.1, with Gnome desktop

I have both ECDSA and ED25519 identities, but from command line, ssh-add command gives error:

> Could not add identity

How to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641082#c22

the bug is relative to gnome-keyring support with ECDSA keys.

The fix which works for me is:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false" >> ~/.config/autostart/gnome-
keyring-ssh.desktop
```

After reboot, ssh-add works correctly from command line:

```
marco@cluster:~$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/marco/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa (/home/marco/.ssh/id_ecdsa)
Identity added: /home/marco/.ssh/id_ed25519 (marco@cluster)
```